# Telepathy and conjured creatures: Can I communicate with them if I don't have the ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

It's not clear to me whether I can communicate with my mind with summoned creatures (with Summon Monsters) if I don't have telepathic abilities.

More precisely, I chose the Tongues Oracle's curse, and so, with some summoned creatures, I cannot communicate.

The curse itself says:

> Whenever you are in combat, you can only speak and understand the selected language.

And, at level 10:

> At 10th level, you can understand any spoken language, as if under the effects of tongues, even during combat.

So, at level 10, there's nothing that restricts the Oracle's thoughts, hence the creature can read my mind and understand what it has to do, especially if the Oracle is thinking in a language they undersand.

Is that right or am I missing something?

I'd like to know if this is correct RAW, with no interpretation, however I'd also like to know if you would permit this?

Comment: I changed 'evocated monsters' to 'conjured creatures', to have this use in-game terms. If this isn't accurate, feel free to rollback or re-edit (another acceptable phrasing would be 'Summoned Monsters' to use the spell name, but conjured creatures is more open-ended)

Comment: @Ifusaso Thank you, I'm using a non english version so there might be some errors here and there

Comment: No worries! It was just a little off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summoned creatures, with exceptions, can only be commanded verbally.

From [Summon Monster](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/) (**emphasis added**)

> It attacks your opponents to the best of its ability. ***If* you can communicate with the creature**, you can direct it not to attack, to attack particular enemies, or to perform other actions.

This was put in with the intent of restricting the spell utility if you summon particularly exotic allies to your side. **The one exception case, any creature that can read your mind** would be able to receive commands from you; any other would only attack anything that it could tell was your enemy.

As a GM, I would not allow you to bypass this restriction because Oracle curses are *supposed* to be a hindrance and the intent of the spell seems pretty clear.